# Bluetooth connects, but does not play sound

Tags: iphone, audio, bluetooth

I've got a Toyota Sienna that has a bluetooth connection for phone audio.  I purchased the GTA Car Kit to connect to the stereo.  This works great with Android devices.  However, I've recently switched to an iPhone 6.  While it will show that it is connected to GTA Car Kit, it almost never actually plays audio over it.  How can I resolve this?  It does work fine for the phone audio, and any other bluetooth device I connect it to.

Comment: what do you mean by 'almost never actually plays'? How often does it play? What do you do in order to make it play for a bit? Make sure the sound is on the highest in both the phone and on the speaker.

Comment: The problem is that it typically would just not make any sound.  I tinkered with things, and I think I've got it working.  Not sure, but it might have been that the bluetooth volume was set too low.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.  I have a GTA Pure Bluetooth system in my 2007 Honda Civic. I have an iPhone 5S that connects automatically to play music about 5-10% of the time. To work around, I have to go into iPhone Settings, Bluetooth, select the ! symbol next to GTA Car Kit, Disconnect, back up one level and reselect GTA Car kit and it then connects 100% of the time. Kind of a pain.

It is almost like there are two levels of Bluetooth connectivity.  My phone connects perfectly 100% of the time but my music does not connect much at all.  In iPhones, look for the tiny headphone icon in the top-right corner of the screen when you have successfully connected to play music.